# Solr/Solrj: How can I determine the total number of documents in an index?

Tags: lucene, solr, solrj

How can I determine the total number of documents in a Solr index using Solrj?

After hours of searching on my own, I actually have an answer (given below); I'm only posting this question so others can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's what I'm using. Is this canonical? Is there a better way?

```
    SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery("*:*");
    q.setRows(0);  // don't actually request any data
    return server.query(q).getResults().getNumFound();
```

Comment: For a quick REST API check, something like: `http://hostname:8983/solr/collection_name_here/query?debug=query&q=*:*` and `numFound` contains the count.

Comment: Something like `wget http://hostname:8983/solr/collection_name_here/query?q=*:*` also does the trick :)`  (and stores the result in a file called `query?q=*:*`)

Comment: Add the rows parameter to return no data, so just the count in "numFound": `http://hostname:8983/solr/collection_name_here/query?q=*:*&rows=0`

Answer (score 3):

Your answer of sending the query `*:*` is probably the best, most general solution. Especially if you are using SolrCloud. However, there is an alternate solution, the [Solr Core Admin API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-STATUS)

Answer (score 2):

Pasting the whole `curl`:

```
curl -s --negotiate -u: 'hostname:8983/solr/my_collection/query?q=*:*&rows=0' | jq '.response | .numFound'
1868000278
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use to get total docs using JSON/PHP hope this helps

```
// Get total number of documents in solr
$solrObj = file_get_contents("http://HOSTNAME:8983/solr/COLLECTION 
NAME/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json");
// var_dump(json_decode($solrObj));
$res_obj = json_decode($solrObj);
$numDocs = $res_obj->response->numFound; 
echo "Total number docs found!: ".$numDocs."<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: solr numFound response]

Depending how you are using it, notice the format options available. For my case XML is ideal.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/drupal/select?q=*%3A*&rows=0&wt=xml
```